# Javascript with Ajax working fine in Mozilla but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm using XMLHTTPREQUEST synchronous and while the request is getting fulfilled, I hide everything on page and show a progress message. This works fine in Mozilla but doesn not in Chrome.

Mozilla firefox:
[image: before submit]

[image: after submit]

For chrome:

[after submit][3]

here is my javascript code:

```
if (valid) {

    document.getElementById('contentwrapper').style.display="none";
    document.getElementById('contentwrapper').style.visibility="hidden";

    var cboxes = document.getElementsByName('items[]');
    var len = cboxes.length;
    var res1;
    var res2;
    var res3;
    var res4;
    var arrResult;

    for (var i = 0; cboxes[i]; ++i) {
        if (cboxes[i].checked) {
            checkedValue = cboxes[i].value;
            arrResult = checkedValue.split(',');
            mobileNo=arrResult[0];
            if(arrResult[0].trim().startsWith('0')){
                res1 = arrResult[0].substring(1,arrResult[0].length);
            }else{
                res1 = arrResult[0];
            }
            res2 = arrResult[1];
            res3 = arrResult[2];
            res4 = arrResult[3];
            requestSender(1, res1, res2, res3, res4);
        }
    }
```

---

```
function requestSender(code, mobile, operator, productCode, amount) {

var http = getHTTPObject();
var enterKeyHandler = true;
var reqNum = 0;
var seqNum = 0;
var dataCount = 0;
var Values = "";
var code;
var comments = "";
reqCode = code;
if (code == 1) {

    var agentcode = '<%=payeeaccountno%>';
    var pin = document.getElementById("mpin").value;
    source = agentcode; // source and agent code both are same.
    operator = operator;
    destination = mobile;
    productCode = productCode;
    if (destination.charAt(0) == '0') {
        destination = destination.replace(/^0+/, "");
    }
    var amt = amount;
    var amtPrd = new Array();
    amtPrd = amt.split("@");
    if (amtPrd.length > 0)
    {
        amount = amtPrd[0];
        //   productCode = amtPrd[1];
    }
    else
    {
        amount = 0;
    }
    clienttype = "SELFCARE";
    vendorcode = '<%=vendorcode%>';
    dataCount = '<%=cryptHandler.encrypt("8",session.getId()+session.getId())%>';
    reqNum = '<%=cryptHandler.encrypt("1",session.getId()+session.getId())%>';
    seqNum = '<%=cryptHandler.encrypt("2",session.getId()+session.getId())%>';
    Values = "&var1=" + escape(agentcode) + "&var2=" + escape(pin) + "&var3=" + escape(amount) + "&var4=" + escape(mobile) + "&var5=" + escape(productCode) + "&var6=" + escape(clienttype) + "&var7=" + escape(operator) + "&var8=" + escape(vendorcode);
}
var varReq = "../Comman/requestForwarder.jsp?page=" + escape("<%=reqPageName%>") + "&reqNum=" + escape(reqNum) + "&seqNum=" + escape(seqNum) + "&dataCount=" + escape(dataCount) + Values;
varReq = varReq.replace(/\+/g, "%2B");
http.open("GET", varReq, false);
httpBuffer = http;
reqCodeBuffer = reqCode;
http.onreadystatechange = responseHandler;
http.send(null);
}
```

Comment: The 3rd image is not there - you might not be able to publish more than 2 links... Also, please read the [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help), this question is not a good one now - you won't likely get a good answer for it.

Comment: Check line 37 of your code

Answer (score 0):

You should actually post some code or at least print the messages in the developer console (ctr + shift + J)

However, the stem of your issue is probably the fact that you are trying to use a synchronous xmlhttpRequest on the "main" execution thread.

Its a bad practice (since It blocks all code from running until the server "answers" your request) and browsers are starting to phase it out. So, if you are using a newer version of chrome, its likely not running the code and complaining about the sync request.

Either use a Web Worker (js version of thread) to run the synchronous XMLHTTPRequest(s) or, better yet, if possible, use the asynchronous version.

Further reading:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests

Comment: m sorry i m new to stackoverflow i don't know how to properly ask a question on this site. but the same code is working on mozilla firefox how is it possible. And i got your point of main thread execution that is genuine point for this reason. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: i have hide everything on page before synchronous request even after this is not working in chrome bt woring in mozilla firefox

Comment: @dineshkumar - the point is, the browser may refuse to process the request, since you performed it on the main thread and asked that everything else be left unserviced while you wait for the server to respond. Hiding stuff before making the request is irrelevant. It would (also) fail in an otherwise empty page in a browser that denied this type of ajax. As for asking good questions, have a look around here: http://stackoverflow.com/help